# How to record RS-485 Modbus communication at PC?

Tags: serial, digital-communications, serial-bus, modbus

I am working on a system with an IPC, RS-485 Modbus communication, and 15 Toyo step motors and drivers. A motor frequently moves without IPC intentionally sending moving instruction and causes a collision. I want to debug by inspecting if IPC really sends out an RS-485 communication signal. Is there any PC software that can record communication with timestamp? Better if decoding Modbus. The one I am using now doesn't have a timestamp, so it is very difficult to debug. Thank you for sharing！

Comment: Yes but product recommendations are off topic here. Type in "terminal software" and "timestamp" into google. And if you can't already connect RS-485 to your PC then you need "RS-485 sniffer" hardware. But if the problem is not real valid RS-485 messages being sent then you need more. A logic analyzer will pick out any digital transmission, valid or not for your protocal, but not electrically corruption. You need a scope for that but more likely a DAQ which can record the analog waveform long term.

Comment: Do you think it’s a better idea to use parity, or FEC?

Comment: your question belongs at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This SO question contains links to Python software that can log MODBUS messages with timestamps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56922031/modbus-error-invalid-message-incomplete-message-received-expected-at-least-2